# Custom Directive w/ Controller in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a custom clock module in AngularJS. The interface I am trying to implement uses the markup `'. Nothing renders and I am not receiving any errors in the console. I'm not sure what's wrong.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>Clock in AngularJS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <clock></clock>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.19/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="clock.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular.module('myApp', ['clock']);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

clock.js:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('clock', [])

    .directive('clock', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: 'true',
            template: '<div>{{datetime}}</div>',
            controller: ['$scope', '$interval', 'dateFilter', function ($scope, $interval, dateFilter) {
                var format, timer, clock;

                format = 'M/d/yy h:mm:ss a';
                timer = $interval(function () {
                    $scope.datetime = dateFilter(new Date(), format);
                }, 1000);

                clock = {
                    start: timer,
                    pause: $interval.cancel(timer)
                };
            }]
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The most probable reason of this happening is because you re declare your module in html script section.

Remove this from html

```
    <script>
        angular.module('myApp', ['clock']);
    </script>
```

and try again

This syntax of module declare a new module. To retrieve existing module use `angular.module('myApp')`

Answer (score 0):

As Chandermani, you have to change your module declaration. You can follow the example of [AnuglarSeed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed), with an `app.js`.

Also, it was still not working. You have to initialize your timer in a function like this :

```
this.start = function() {
    timer = $interval(function () {
        $scope.datetime = dateFilter(new Date(), format);
     }, 1000);
}

this.pause = function() {
    $interval.cancel(timer);
}
```

And also, add a link function to your directive to call the start function.

Your directive can be this:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myapp', [])

.directive('clock', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: 'true',
        template: '<div>{{datetime}}</div>',
        controller: ['$scope', '$interval', 'dateFilter', function ($scope, $interval, dateFilter) {
            var format, timer, clock;
            format = 'M/d/yy h:mm:ss a';

            this.start = function() {
              timer = $interval(function () {
                $scope.datetime = dateFilter(new Date(), format);
              }, 1000);
            }

            this.pause = function() {
              $interval.cancel(timer);
            }
        }],
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
          ctrl.start();
        }
    };
});
```

I've created a plunker for the full solution:
http://plnkr.co/edit/wjfAogybFvoxIYnQVJgg?p=preview